# Hibernate LockMode

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, locking

Can you please explain to me why the test is failing which means the lock is not working ?

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        int id = initDB();
        Myobj myobj= dao.get(id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
       
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> delete(id));
        thread.start();
        thread.join();

        Assert.assertNotNull(dao.get(id, LockMode.NONE));
   }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void delete(long id){
           Myobj myobj = new Myobj(id);
           dao.delete(myobj);
    }
```

dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public Myobj get(long id, LockMode mode){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Myobj.class,id,mode);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Myobj myobj){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(Myobj.class.getName(),myobj);
    }
.
.
```

I'm using Mysql5 and Hibernate 5.4.0

I can see from hibernate logs that he included the lock in the sql request:

`lock in share mode`

Comment: For a manually created thread it's really anybody's guess, but I'd start with checking if you're actually getting a different `Session` inside `get` and `delete` (because if not, the shared lock probably just gets promoted to an exclusive lock)

Comment: How do you want to know that it "works"? Your thread could throw an exception and you don't see that anywhere. Also, I don't know if you can just start a thread like that. I don't think transactions will work in such threads.

Comment: @crizzis different Sessions

Comment: @ChristianBeikov the PESSIMISTIC_READ should block other transactions from modifying/deleting the entity until the current transaction is finished. 
My test is failing => the other thread had no problem deleting the entity despite the lock

Comment: Huh, weird. What about connections? Does `((SessionImpl) session).connection()` return different connections inside `get` and `delete`?

Comment: @crizzis by logging the connection inside get and delete I can see different connection instances

Comment: How do you want to know that delete failed? There is no exception handler registered on the thread that you use so you won't see a lock acquisition exception. The `get` method might lock the row, but the second thread will try to do the delete and just run into a timeout or something else end will terminate with a TX rollback. The main thread then continues.

Comment: By checking that the entity still exists in database : Assert.assertNotNull(dao.get(id, LockMode.NONE));